# Error in Initialising correlation structure in nlme

Tags: r, matrix, correlation, nlme

I am trying to run a regression (using the gls function in nlme) in which I account for shared phylogenetic history, and my tree isn't ultrametric. I made the correlation matrix myself (because some of my data points are along the same branch of a tree, and it was just easier to do it myself). I keep getting the same error regarding the correlation matrix. My code:

```
s<-read.csv("vcv.csv", header=T)
cov_matrix<- as.matrix(apply(s[,-1],2,as.numeric))
row.names(cov_matrix) <- s[,1]
cormatrix<-cov2cor(cov_matrix)         #the actual correlation matrix
dat<-read.csv("data.csv", header=T)

tip.heights <- diag(cov_matrix)
fit <- gls(y~x, 
           correlation=corSymm(cormatrix[lower.tri(cormatrix)]), 
           weights = varFixed(~tip.heights),                #for non-ultrametric tree 
           data=dat)
```

And the error:

```
Error in Initialize.corSymm(X[[i]], ...) : 
  initial values for "corSymm" must be between -1 and 1
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: You get this error if you supply correlations of exactly -1 or 1. Such values are not sensible starting values.

Comment: You can reproduce with `Initialize(corSymm(value = c(1, 0.1, -0.1, 0, 0.2, 0)), data = matrix(1:16, 4))`.